# How to define lot of seekbars in one loop?

Tags: android

```
    final SeekBar seekbar2=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
    final SeekBar seekbar3=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar3);
    final SeekBar seekbar4=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar4);
    final SeekBar seekbar5=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar5);
    final SeekBar seekbar6=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar6);
    final SeekBar seekbar7=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar7);
    final SeekBar seekbar8=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar8);
    final SeekBar seekbar9=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar9);
    final SeekBar seekbar10=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar10);
    final SeekBar seekbar11=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar11);
    final SeekBar seekbar12=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar12);
    final SeekBar seekbar13=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar13);
    final SeekBar seekbar14=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar14);
    final SeekBar seekbar15=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar15);
    final SeekBar seekbar16=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar16);
    final SeekBar seekbar17=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar17);
    final SeekBar seekbar18=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar18);
```

How to do this in one for loop? Maybe like this?
for(i=2;i<19;i++)
{final SeekBar seekbar[]=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar[i])}

Comment: If you're going to use a loop you can't make the SeekBars final and accessible outside the loop.

Comment: It's not important to be final

Comment: @Matej Livajić my fix is working?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
int resourceId;
SeekBar[] mySeekBarArray = new SeekBar [17];

for(i=2;i<19;i++){
   resourceId=getResources().getIdentifier("seekBar"+i, "id",getPackageName()); 

   SeekBar mySeekBarArray[i-2]=(SeekBar) findViewById(resourceId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write all your resource ids to an int array and loop them. For storing the seekbars I'd suggest a List or an array, as having so many variables is kind of redundant. Here's an example:

```
List<SeekBar> seekbars = new ArrayList<SeekBar>();
int[] seekbarIds = new int[] { R.id.seekbar1, R.id.seekbar2, R.id.seekbar3 };

for (int seekbarId : seekbarIds) {
    seekbars.add((SeekBar) findViewById(seekbarId));
}
```

And you would use a specific (say 2nd) seekbar like this:

```
seekbars.get(1).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```